# Can I verify in a postConstruct that <task:annotation-driven /> is set?

Tags: java, spring

I have the following class that is in a library:

```
public class TaskExecutor {
  @PostConstruct
  public void postConstruct() {
    // should fail if <task:annotation-driven /> is not set,
    // because execute() needs to run
  }

  @Scheduled(fixedDelay = 1000)
  public void execute() {
    // do stuff that always needs to run
  }
}
```

I want to fail the PostConstruct if ***task:annotation-driven*** is not set in the spring context. The idea is that a developer using this library will fail hard on spring start if the setting is missing, instead of soft after deployment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd advise against that because you're tying your app to Spring more than necessary, but:

I think you can do it by injecting the ApplicationContext and asking it for the existence of a bean that is always set by `<task:annotation-driven />`, e.g. 
[`AsyncAnnotationBeanPostProcessor`](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/scheduling/annotation/AsyncAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.html)

Comment: Yes, that works perfectly. I'm not to worried about tying to Spring, considering I already use @Scheduled, plus some other Spring classes.